# How can I separate part of json in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json in the following format and I just want to save 2 parts of it. But I get it as separate characters. Can you please help me?

```
for data in results['results']:
   dictionary = dict(zip("title:", data['title']))
   dictionary = dict(zip("uuid:", data['uuid']))
```

Json

```
        results": [
            {
              "title": "subject1",
              "ja_pub_yyyy": 1395,
              "uuid": "86ae6",
              "external_link": null,
              "fulltext_status": 1,
},
  {
              "title": "subject2",
              "ja_pub_yyyy": 1395,
              "uuid": "86ae6",
              "external_link": null,
              "fulltext_status": 1,
}
]
```

new_result

```
    results": [
        {
          "title": "subject1",
          "id": "86ae6",
 },
        {
          "title": "subject2",
          "id": "86ae6",
 }]
```

Comment: Where did `subject2` come from? The `results` dictionary doesn't have it. And what is `new_result`? Is it the result of your code? Or is it the **expected** result?

Comment: You are right
I fixed it

Comment: second part is expected result

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but what you have here is not "JSON", as you've already converted it to a list of dictionaries, otherwise you could not access it with ``results['results']`` and ``data['title']`` - and for your problem, it does not matter that the original data was JSON, your problem is rather, you want to create a new list of dict from an existing list of dict, by using specific keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating each `dict` properly. It is more simple:

```py
new_result = []
for data in results['results']:
    l = ((k,data[k]) for k in ("title","uuid"))
    dictionary = dict(l)
    new_result.append(dictionary)
```

I have demonstrated collecting each `dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks, but this code only worked for one element, not the whole array

Comment: What array is that?

Comment: subject1, subject2 ,...

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way too

```
result = [{'title':r['title'],'uuid':r['uuid']} for r in results]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop over the json and extract the object property into the new array.
eg:

```
results= [
            {
              "title": "subject1",
              "ja_pub_yyyy": 1395,
              "uuid": "86ae6",
              "external_link": None,
              "fulltext_status": 1,
},
  {
              "title": "subject1",
              "ja_pub_yyyy": 1395,
              "uuid": "86ae6",
              "external_link": None,
              "fulltext_status": 1,
}
]
res = []
for data in results:
    res.append({'name': data['title'], 'id': data['uuid']})
print(res)
```